# Changes in not model not adding methods to classes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I made changes to two classes to link them by this way

```
    class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :customer,:foreign_key=>'name_id'
    end

    class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :accounts
    end
```

I have data in two tables that has the the referencing key 'name' in Customer and 'name_id' in Account matched. But still when I go to 'script/console' and type

```
                      Account.find(0).customer
```

I get **nil** even when there is matching data! What is my mistake here? Sorry if its a dumb question by I'm new to rails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had me thinking per your comment to Shyam. When adding your custom keys, are the fields in there own migration file, or were they included in the migration files when you first ran db:migrate? If these columns are already there, then yes, simply saving the model should do the trick.

You could do a quick: `Account` and `Customer` in your rails console to make sure these classes are built correctly, and it's the relationship that's giving you the issues.

On a side note, I'd move away from using "name" as your primary key as soon as possible. It's bad design and will cause you headaches down the road. This isn't just a rails thing, just think, how many John Smith's are in the phone book? You'd then have to use a combo key with address, and maybe more to get a unique row. And if you think about it, the phone book has a unique phone number as the identifier, it's just sorted by name.

Comment: I better follow the conventions :D

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, I think you need to set `:foreign_key` and `:primary_key` on both associations.

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer,:foreign_key=>'name_id', :primary_key=>'name'
end

class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :accounts, :primary_key=>'name', :foreign_key=>'name_id'
end
```

Comment: Still not working, is it enough if I just save my model file? because I dont see the changes getting reflected in console

Answer (score 0):

You really should be following Rails conventions: the foreign key in your `accounts` table should be `customer_id`. Changing it to that will solve the problems you're having.

Answer (score 0):

Primary keys start at 1, try: `Account.find(1).customer`